# Show mounted USB device on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, mount, ls

I want to find `/dev/` location of a USB device. The main thing is, it's not a drive or any other mass storage , it is basically only a USB modem and `wvdial` can not detect it. So I just want the location of my device, so that I can do something to get it detected.

**System log after connecting device:**

```
[ 1162.830797] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848198] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1505<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848205] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848209] usb 3-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848212] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848215] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1162.848957] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"<br>
Aug 18 16:30:32 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 4 was not an MTP device<br>
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1163.847402] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0<br>
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1163.857317] sr1: scsi-1 drive
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1163.857570] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1<br>
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1163.857741] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5<br>
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC kernel: [ 1163.881325] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 3 ep 14 with no TDs queued?<br>
Aug 18 16:30:33 hunter-350V5C-351V5C-3540VC-3440VC usb_modeswitch: switching device 12d1:1505 on 003/004<br>
```

Comment: `lsusb` to list usb devices. The **6th column** is the *device ID*. `dmesg | grep deviceID`. You should also search online for that device ID to more information.

Comment: hey i know what my device is in output of lsusb , but lsusb do not tell the mount point, and dmesg too shows the device but not mount location.
thanks for taking interest

Comment: `df` shows mount point at last column (Mount on)..

Comment: Uh, if it is not a storage device, you don't actually mount it in that sense, and it will definitely not be visible with `df`. Instead, you should have the OS to detect the device and use the correct driver so that it will appear in /dev. Most likely things that happen when you plug the modem in are shown in `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog` and the logs might even state the device file assosiated with the modem. Please post the logs related to plugging in the device here.

Comment: @zagrimsan , now can u help me track the device location in /dev/ttyUSB or something??

Comment: Oops, sorry, you had already posted the info...

Comment: @zagrimsan, i posted info after you said so , i have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log you posted reveals the device ID is **12d1:1505**

Googling I found this modem needs to [mode switched](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/usb_modeswitch/)

According to the [ArchLinux package manifest](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/usb_modeswitch/) a config for your modem is present, so it should be included upstream and available for any up-to-date distro.

1.) Install the `usb_modeswitch` package

2.) **Optional:** If the udev rule doesn't kick in manually force it

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -I -W -c 12d1:1505
```

[More information available on this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem)

Comment: hey , i too think it needs to be mode switch, I hace installed usb_modeswitch, now how to enable?? thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I have setup usbmodems for nat with shorewall and stuff but I've almost but all forgotten what I did.

If it's making a dev node at all do this just before you plug it:

```
udevadm monitor
```

You may need to run as root/sudo I can't remember.
This used to tell me where stuff was mounted at etc hopefull this will give you the dev node to access the modem :)